# How Get UI Elements of a Window? Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, applescript

How Translate this AppleScript code to Swift ?

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari" to get UI elements of first window
```

I already reached to first window of "Safari", but I don't know how to get the UI Elements

```swift
let pid = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications.first(where: {$0.localizedName == "Safari"})?.processIdentifier
let appRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid!)
var windows: AnyObject?
_ = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appRef, kAXWindowsAttribute as CFString, &windows)
if let firstWindow = (windows as? [AXUIElement])?.first{
    print(firstWindow)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue()` to query for the children of the window, and the children of the children, and so on.

Myself likes to add extensions over existing types, when possible, for better clarity:

```swift
extension AXUIElement {
    var children: [AXUIElement]? {
        var childrenPtr: CFTypeRef?
        AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appRef, kAXChildrenAttribute as CFString, &childrenPtr)
        return childrenPtr as? [AXUIElement]
    }
}
```

You can then use it in your code:

```swift
if let firstWindow = (windows as? [AXUIElement])?.first{
    print(firstWindow, firstWindow.children)
}
```

You can take it a little bit further, and simplify the `AXUIElement` consumer code by adding more functionality to the extension:

```swift
extension AXUIElement {
    
    static func from(pid: pid_t) -> AXUIElement { AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid) }
    
    var windows: [AXUIElement]? { value(forAttribute: kAXWindowsAttribute) }
    
    var children: [AXUIElement]? { value(forAttribute: kAXChildrenAttribute) }
    
    func value<T>(forAttribute attribute: String) -> T? {
        var attributeValue: CFTypeRef?
        AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(self, attribute as CFString, &attributeValue)
        return attributeValue as? T
    }
}

let pid = ...
let app = AXUIElement.from(pid: pid!)
if let firstWindow = app.windows?.first{
    print(firstWindow, firstWindow.children)
}
```